# Wiring a spring managed bean from a class which is not managed by spring

Tags: spring

Is it possible to wire a *Spring Managed Bean* into a class which is not
managed by Spring IoC?
Let's say there are two classes `ClassA` (not managed by spring) and
`ClassB` (managed by Spring) is it possible to wire `ClassB` in `ClassA`.

This was a recent question I came across and I had no clue how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible. You'll need an `ApplicationContextAware` implementation for getting the Spring Managed Bean instance using the `ApplicationContext`. It's an old Spring Framework trick.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public final class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

     private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanClass);
    }    
}
```

Then you must use `BeanUtil::getBean` static method in ClassA to get the ClassB instance within the `ApplicationContext`.

```
public class ClassA {    

    private ClassB classB;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassA - " + getClassB().toString();
    }    

    // Lazy initialization of ClassB to avoid NullPointerException
    private ClassB getClassB() {

        if (classB == null) {
           classB = BeanUtil.getBean(ClassB.class);
        }

        return classB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about "wiring" if Spring is not managing the bean.
Instead,
just solve the problem of "How do I get a reference to a managed bean into a non-managed bean".

In your example,
since `ClassA` is not managed by Spring you must be creating it somewhere.
Pass a reference to `ClassB` to `ClassA` when you create the instance of `ClassA`.